# Why the size of the directory is more then 79mb but in fact its about 19mb?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
s = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile") + "\\Pictures";
            string[] extensions = { "*.bmp", "*.jpg", "*.png", "*.gif" };//add extensions you want to filter first
            var photosfiles = extensions.SelectMany(x => Directory.GetFiles(s, x));
            //string[] photosfiles = Directory.GetFiles(s, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            for (int i = 0; i < photosfiles.ToArray().Length; i++)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo((photosfiles.ToArray()[i]));
                DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(tempphotos);
                long dirSize = DirSize(d);
                //if copying the file would take the directory over 50MB then don't do it
                if ((dirSize + fi.Length) <= 24117248)
                    fi.CopyTo(tempphotos + "\\" + fi.Name,true);
                else
                    break;
            }
```

What i changed is this :

```
string[] extensions = { "*.bmp", "*.jpg", "*.png", "*.gif" };//add extensions you want to filter first
var photosfiles = extensions.SelectMany(x => Directory.GetFiles(s, x));
```

Before this two lines i had one line only:

```
string[] photosfiles = Directory.GetFiles(s, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

With this line it was working but after changed to the two lines above its not working.

I had to change this lines and add now .ToArray()

```
for (int i = 0; i < photosfiles.ToArray().Length; i++)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo((photosfiles.ToArray()[i]));
```

And then the result in the end is that

dirSize + fi.Length = 19526637
And fi.Length = 7916391

So its jumping right to the break.

When i used the first time only one line string[] photosfiles = Directory.GetFiles(s, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

And then without the .ToArray()

It was working good it was copying the files and then do the break;

Why now its not working after changed to this two lines and added the .ToArray() ?

Comment: This question is extremely hard to follow, but using `Directory.GetFiles()` you're including all files in that directory and any subdirectories, whereas when you're using `extensions.SelectMany()` you're filtering for files that have `.bmp` `.jpg` `.png` and `.gif` extensions

Comment: Have you also tried unhiding (http://www.wikihow.com/Unhide-Folders-in-Windows-7 ) all of the folders just to make sure there isn't anything hidden in there?

Comment: There are 2 possibilities: 1. Your folder `photosfiles` may have some files before, have you checked it? 2. There are many pictures in the folder `s` and its size would be possibly greater than `25MB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I follow everything, but a few things.  This line:

```
var photosfiles = extensions.SelectMany(x => Directory.GetFiles(s, x));
```

is building a query, but not an actual array. The `ToArray()` runs the query and builds an array when called.  In your code, you actually build the array multiple times, which is unnecessary.  Instead, you can loop over the query by using a foreach loop:

```
foreach(var file in photoFiles)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
    // Your code here
}
```

A small note too is that your comment says to prevent the copy if it is over 50 MB, but that number is actually 23 MB.

Comment: lukegraviti yes forogot to change it the note is about 50mb i just tried few sizes for testing.